# How is it possible for a not effective final variable be used within a lambda

Tags: lambda, java-8

I am curious why the following code is valid (for sure not best practice), because I always thought a variable in this case `(order)` within a lambda needs to be final or at least is effective final. So how is it possible to increase the order value for each ref? The ref contains increasing numbers 0, 10, 20, ...

```
public class A {

  private int order = 0;

  public void addOrder() {
    this.order = 0;
    getRefsSomewhere().stream().forEach(ref -> updateRef(ref, order+=10));
  }
}
```

If I just change it slightly it doesn't compile anymore (as expected)

```
public class A {
  public void addOrder() {
    int order = 0;
    getRefsSomewhere().stream().forEach(ref -> updateRef(ref, order+=10));
  }
}
```

Any pointers why the first example works?

Comment: In a lambda, only local variables need to be final, but instance variables don't have to be final

Comment: The term “effectively final” does not even apply to fields.